# Best method of jogging

Tags: weight-loss, cardio, walking, jogging

Which is the best technique of jogging out of following 2 that will have a better / faster results when it comes to weight reduction?

1. Start by walking for about 5 mins, then continuously jog for 40 mins straight with a constant speed of 8 km/h and then finish the workout by walking another 10 mins.
2. Start by walking for about 5 mins, then jog for about 20 mins with a constant speed of 8 km/h, again walk for 5 mins, jog for another 20 mins in the same speed (8 km/h) and then finish the session by walking another 5 mins.

Both workouts spend the same amount of time (55 mins)

**Sorry if the question is not following the stack rules**

Answer (score 1):

The two will burn the same amount of energy, and so there will not be any difference between the two in terms of fat loss.

If you were running at a pace that you could sustain for 20 minutes but not for 40 minutes, then putting the walking break in the middle would be beneficial because it would allow you to run faster than you could if you did all the running in one 40 minute block.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. I actually can jog for 40 mins straight at the same speed of 8 km/h, but I was having a doubt that the multiple intermittent walking breaks in between would have a better impact on weight reduction than having no walking intervals at all

Comment: @Sahan De Silva It would have a better impact if you could run two periods of 20 minutes not at 8 kmh but at 9 kmh, for example.

Comment: @Enivid That would be a great idea, but to tell you the truth, 9 km/h is too much for me, but yeah!! as you said.. If I could do 2 20 mins slots with 9 km/h, that would have better impact for sure

Comment: If 9 kmh is too much, you could do 8.1 kmh or 8.05 kmh. In other words, the highest speed that isn’t “too much” for you to be running at for 20 minutes.

Comment: I see. Let me try 8.2 km/h and see how it works. Thanks for the suggestion